# Multiples of 3 print hippity and on multiples of 4 print hop?

Tags: java

```
//Name of Program:  HippityHop.java
//Entered by:   No Name
//Date:  10/19/2020

import java.util.Scanner;  // Needed for the Scanner class


public class HippityHop
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 
  
 // get scanner to read input
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  
for(int x=1; x <= 100; x++){
  if(x % 3 && x % 4) {
     System.out.println(x);
  }else{
     if(x % 3 == 0){
        System.out.println("Hippity");
     }
     if(x % 4 == 0){
        System.out.println("Hop");
        
        }
      }
  }
```

}
}

I am trying to create a program that on multiples of 3 it prints "Hippity" and on multiples of 4 it prints "hop". I seem to be getting a bad operand error. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: `x % 3` is not a boolean expression (does not evaluate to true/false) and makes no sense as written in the if block. Perhaps you meant `if (x % 3 == 0 && x % 4 == 0)`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels when I changed that in the code it did give me feedback, however, it did give me the incorrect solution. On multiples of 4 and 3 it just lists the number and for non multiples of either it fills it in as "hippity" or "hoppity"

Comment: Well that is your logic.  If the want the code below that to also execute then it should not be an `else`

Comment: *"On multiples of 4 and 3 it just lists the number"* Of course, since that's what you wrote the code to do. What else did you expect/want the program to do? Print `Hippity Hop` on one line? If so, why don't you just do that?

Comment: What happens if the number is a multiple of both three and four?

Answer (score 2):

The following expression:

```
if(x % 3 && x % 4) {
```

Isn't a proper one. What `x%3` is doing is calculating the modulus. You never compared it to anything, so it's throwing a bad operand error. That's like saying in real life:

```
if x modulus 3 then do this
```

Or, just for the sake of the argument (and to make it easier to understand), it's like saying:

```
if x subtract 3 then do this
```

Instead, it should be `if(x%3!=0 && x%4!=0)`, like so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  // Needed for the Scanner class


public class HippityHop
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 
  
 // get scanner to read input
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  
for(int x=1; x <= 100; x++){
  if(x % 3 !=0 && x % 4 !=0) {
     System.out.println(x);
  }else{
     if(x % 3 == 0){
        System.out.println("Hippity");
     }
     if(x % 4 == 0){
        System.out.println("Hop");
        
        }
      }
  }
} }
```